# Suppose that $V$ is a vector space and $H$ is an affine plane which contains a hyperplane $H'$, then either $H = V$ or $H= H'$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $V$ is a vector space and $H$ is an affine plane which contains a hyperplane $H'$, then either $H = V$ or $H= H'$. Why is this true? I think I should use some version of Hahn-Banach, but I do not have one at my disposal that can solve it.

Comment: There must be some relation ship between V and H but you haven't said what it was!

Comment: It is in $V$ of course.

Comment: So you probably meant that (1) $H'$ is an affine hyperplane of $V$, not of $H$; and (2) $H$ is not specifically an affine *plane*, but some affine subspace of $V$. *Then* there’s indeed enough data. Am I right about (1) and (2)?

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\;H\neq H'\implies \exists h\in H\setminus H'\;$ . Since $\;H'\le V\;$ is a hyperplane, we get that $\;\langle H',\,h\rangle=V\;$. Thus, for any $\;v\in V\;$ there exist $\;h'\in H\,\,\text{ and a scalar}\;\beta\;$  s.t.
$$v=h'+\beta h\in H'+H=H\implies V\subset H\implies V=H$$